# Does anyone know of a Python script which mimics TradingView's editor?

Tags: python, github, pine-script, tradingview-api

Please let me know if this question is not allowed, as I got a warning when asking it.  I'm looking for a Python script which mimics TradingView's pine script editor.

What I mean by this is TradingView's editor goes through each candle on the chart and runs all the code for each candle (or tick maybe?) I'm not 100% sure exactly how it does it, but I need to convert a pine script into Python and to do this I need a script which grabs candle data from somewhere, then runs through the data, running a function onTick() or onNewCandle() which runs each tick or new candle.  Then I can convert my pine to python and put it in that function.

I'm just wondering if there is a program or framework or something which does this.  If not, I may need to build one, but this would save a lot of time. Thanks in advance and pls let me know if this question is not fitting for this site and I will delete it if so.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind explaining further your intentions, there can be other solutions out there, eventually. I'll give you one example: [this](https://github.com/Robswc/tradingview-webhooks-bot/tree/master/tradingview-webhooks-bot) link shows how to hook-up TradingView alerts with a Flask microenvironment server, and it uses [this](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) library to connect to a variety of cryptocurrencies exchanges.

It does not mimic anything at all, but it saves you the burden of having to re-program a Pine strategy in Python and allows for hooking your Pine Study directly into a trading bot in Python. Anyway, just saying.